# Visual Studio crashes when trying to open an existing project

Tags: visual-studio-mac

So, when I'm about to open a solution, the VS just crashes.

[[image: Screenshot before the crash]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNwbU.png)

I don't really know what I should attach here, so there is a little piece of the error code after force quit... if it's needed, I can insert there the whole, but it's quite long.

A piece of the error code:

```
Process:               VisualStudio [1509]
Path:                  /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio
Identifier:            com.microsoft.visual-studio
Version:               8.8.0.2913 (8.8.0.2913)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           VisualStudio [1509]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-19 13:52:01.224 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C5048k)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.1 (18P53017c)


Time Awake Since Boot: 7000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  GUI Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1748]

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000307  rbx: 0x0000000001050002  rcx: 0x00007fff203c2c1c  rdx: 0x0000000000000307
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000307  rbp: 0x00007ffee8f2a520  rsp: 0x00007ffee8f2a4e8
   r8: 0x0000000000017a11   r9: 0xffffffff00000000  r10: 0x00007fff889af930  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000050000  r13: 0x0000000000000307  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000106cf1600
  rip: 0x00007fff203c2517  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000106cda3aa
  
Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Here are some more lines, that should be something to work with as this is the crashed thread's error. pthread_kill, abort, cache_getImp?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: GUI Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2034c452 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2037a610 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff202cd720 abort + 120
3   libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a58ce86 mono_post_native_crash_handler + 102 (mini-posix.c:1168)
4   libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a5248a8 mono_handle_native_crash + 632 (mini-exceptions.c:3440)
5   libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a58bbb5 sigterm_signal_handler + 85 (mini-posix.c:256)
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff203bed7d _sigtramp + 29
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff20216d00 cache_getImp + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff20216d00 cache_getImp + 144
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e824bb -[NSView _recursiveGatherAllKeyViewCandidatesInArray:] + 895
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e824bb -[NSView _recursiveGatherAllKeyViewCandidatesInArray:] + 895
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e820b3 _NSComputeFirstKeyViewVisuallyInDirection + 60
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e81e24 -[NSWindow _findFirstKeyViewInDirection:forKeyLoopGroupingView:] + 74
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e81b55 _replacementKeyViewAlongKeyViewPath + 597
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e814da -[NSView nextValidKeyView] + 230
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e97c3f __82-[NSAutoFillHeuristicController showAutoFillIfNecessaryFor:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 89
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff234e42e8 ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke + 25
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204725a2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2047244c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 437
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20471113 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204706ce CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286ea6a0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286ea2f2 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 283
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286ea1bf _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c86da5 _DPSNextEvent + 883
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c8556b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1366
26  libgdk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib       0x0000000110dd1797 poll_func + 295 (gdkeventloop-quartz.c:779)
27  libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010eb445ab g_main_context_iterate + 366
28  libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010eb4485b g_main_loop_run + 207
29  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib       0x0000000110911c02 gtk_main + 242 (gtkmain.c:1257)
30  ???                             0x000000011c694de6 0 + 4771630566
31  ???                             0x000000011c694d53 0 + 4771630419
32  ???                             0x000000011c694c0b 0 + 4771630091
33  ???                             0x000000010e5bba0d 0 + 4535859725
34  ???                             0x00000001047e0673 0 + 4370335347
35  ???                             0x00000001047e01fb 0 + 4370334203
36  ???                             0x00000001047e0325 0 + 4370334501
37  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a481aa2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2354 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
38  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a691197 do_runtime_invoke + 53 (object.c:3052) [inlined]
39  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a691197 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 135 (object.c:3220)
40  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a69965e do_exec_main_checked + 94 (object.c:5180)
41  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a4e1f5e mono_jit_exec_internal + 14 (driver.g.c:1391) [inlined]
42  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a4e1f5e mono_jit_exec + 414 (driver.g.c:1336)
43  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a4e51c5 main_thread_handler + 75 (driver.g.c:1473) [inlined]
44  libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010a4e51c5 mono_main + 9397 (driver.g.c:2769)
45  com.microsoft.visual-studio     0x000000010467179f main + 2671
46  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20395621 start + 1
```

Comment: Try to encapsulate blocks of code with back quote's so we can read it clearer. ```

Comment: @RoyBerris Done. Sorry for that, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, so seems like 8.8.1 update solved the issue, so far at least.